# Visual code studio for C++: Seperate terminals for input and output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In using VS Code studio for C++. The same terminal uses to take input from user and if you have court<< statements it prints out on the same terminal which mixes up the input from the output.

For example, the following comprises of both input and output into a mix-up:

```
Other Exception
Not enough memory
17476 2249
4233 0
5175 428523
4989 508317
46515400Not enough memory
Other Exception
Exception: vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 428523) >= this->size() (which is 5175)
Exception: vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 508317) >= this->size() (which is 4989)
848400 7053
-8995 4278
83283 8616
41063 4118
78317Not enough memory
Exception: A is negative
```

Is it possible to have two separate terminal one just for input and other for output ?

Comment: This "Visual Code Studio" is a fun new trend. Especially when you consider that the question text correctly says VS Code. Might need a tag alias. Also, the tag visual-c++ is something *completely* different. I've swapped the tags on that.

Comment: As a more serious comment, error messages should be printed to `std::cerr`. It won't fix your issue outright, but it gives you a better practice. You could also just log errors to a file. Or, best yet, don't take your input through stdin. Unless this is stemming from an attempt at a "competitive" coding challenge.